# Visual studio 2017 reactjs without typescript

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2017

I'm a .net web developer experimenting with react js. Mostly I've used create-react-app in vs code but would like to try to see what I can do with visual studio 2017. Having tried this I noticed it uses typescript by default. Is there anyway not to use typescript? I don't know this language yet. Or should I really take the time to learn typescript and trying to develop in javascript is not a good idea?

Comment: Couldn't you use a project created with create-react-app in Visual Studio? I'm not sure, since I don't know much about VS myself (only code)

Comment: I've seen tutorials where you take the app created with create-react-app, eject it and put it in the solution but those samples were created with the typescript option. I didn't know you could just use javascript in the typescript files but I suspect there will be more things to do before I can get the application running

Comment: You _could_ use JS in the typescript files, but I'm suggesting to make an app with CRA's default mode, which creates a JS+babel project

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is a superset of Javascript. This means valid Javascript is valid Typescript. You don't need to learn Typescript if you don't want to, just write Javascript and everything should work out-of-the-box.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm sure there will be a few additional steps to get it going but I'll give it a shot this week

Answer (score 0):

Also will be needed configure tsconfig.json for remove some checkers